# Visual Basic: How to import string into datagrid

Tags: string, visual-studio, datagrid, basic

I am writing a visual basic Form where I want to import a csv from a php script to the datagrid from my form but I can't figure out how to do it.

So what I am doing right now is this: I import the string from my php script:

```
myString = myWebClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/balance_history.php")
```

The php script echoes the data as following:

```
$string .= $transaction["type"].",";
$string .= $transaction["description"].","; 
$string .= $transaction["amount"].",";
$string .= "\n";
echo $string;
```

So how do I import this string into my datagrid? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend you to try JGRID.
It has pretty awesome features and i think it will be helpful for your case too.
http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: thanks for the tip, but that doesn't help me with Visual Basic as far as I see...

Answer (score 0):

For everyone else who needs help with that problem: Found a Solution that works really well. 
I split the string into the single values, created a datatable and inserted the values:

```
Dim table As New DataTable
table.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
table.Columns.Add("Beschreibung", GetType(String))
table.Columns.Add("Menge", GetType(Double))
table.Rows.Add(content(0), content(1), content(2),
```